# What is the similarity between the LCR circuit and a forced damped oscillation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, harmonic-oscillator

In my physics class, my teacher told me this equation
$$L\frac{d^2q}{dt^2} + R\frac{dq}{dt} + \frac{q}{C} = \nu \sin \omega t$$
where $L$ is the self inductance and $\omega$ is the driving frequency. It represents an LCR circuit applied to an AC voltage.

It is extremely similar to the equation of forced damped oscillations
$$m\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} + b\frac{dx}{dt} + kx = F \cos \omega t$$
where $b$ is the damping constant and $\omega$ is the driving frequency of oscillations.

Is there a similarity between these two physical phenomenon?

Comment: What is $x$ here? Did you intend to write $q$?

Comment: Sorry. I edited the question.

Comment: As a minor point, in the case of forced damped  oscillations, if you change the time $t$ to $ t \to t + \pi/ (2 \omega )$ the equations look even more similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charge oscillates between inductor and capacitor which is known as LC oscillation and where the resistance do the damping work here by dissipating it . Same as a damped oscillation in SHM it's the damped charge oscillation of LCR circuit. Here is a rough graph
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, it is the same math.  If you make a plot of charge vs time for one and displacement vs time for the other, they would behave the same.

A resistor dissipates energy like a damper, an inductor stores energy like a mass with inertia (I would actually consider an inductor more analogous to a flywheel.   But that's kind of just "enhanced inertia" I guess.)  And a capacitor stores energy linearly with charge like a spring does with displacement.